# My form doesn't calculate the gross salary

Tags: php, forms

I created a form in which I want to enter a gross salary ($salBrut) and when I press the "Calculate" button, it shows me the $salNet, which is the NET salary.

So far the form automatically has nothing in the input text, and it gives me -299 result directly, without letting me calculate the desired salary! And even if I enter any value, it still won't read it...

What should I do in order to make it recognise my value entered in the ?
*$contributii are the taxes*

Code is below:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <label>Introduceti salariul dvs. <u>brut</u></label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name"salarBrut" value=""/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Calculate!"/>
</form>



<?php

$salBrut = $_GET['salarBrut'];
$contributii = array("pensii" => 105,
            "sanatate" => 55,
            "somaj" => 5,
            "impozit" => 134);
$totContrib = array_sum($contributii);

$salNet = $salBrut-$totContrib;

echo "Salariul net este $salNet";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <label>Introduceti salariul dvs. <u>brut</u></label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="salarBrut" value="<?=(isset( $_GET['salarBrut'] ))?$_GET['salarBrut']:''?>"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="btn"/>
</form>



<?php
    if( isset( $_GET['salarBrut'] ) ){
        echo "sal :".$salBrut = $_GET['salarBrut'];
        $contributii = array("pensii" => 105,
                    "sanatate" => 55,
                    "somaj" => 5,
                    "impozit" => 134);
        echo "<br>sum :".$totContrib = array_sum($contributii);

        echo "<br>net :".$salNet = $salBrut-$totContrib;

        echo "<br>Salariul net este $salNet";    
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the target page for the form:

```
<form method="get" action="your_php_file.php">
```

And also your php code will execute itself **BEFORE** and **AFTER** you send the form.

If you want the php code execute itself only **AFTER** you send the form, use

```
if(isset($_GET['salarBrut'])){ 
    // your code 
}
```

Comment: and remember to [sanitize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php?lq=1) your request!

Comment: If I'm editing the PHP in the HTML I don't have to tell the target where to get it, you just have to leave it blank. It's the standards definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your input has an error in it. You need it be

```
<input type="text" name="salarBrut" value=""/>
```

Note the `name=` bit.

Also, I would probably POST the form and set it's action to be the current page:

```
<?php

    $salBrut = $_POST['salarBrut'];

    $contributii = array("pensii" => 105,
            "sanatate" => 55,
            "somaj" => 5,
            "impozit" => 134);
    $totContrib = array_sum($contributii);

    $salNet = $salBrut-$totContrib;

    echo "Salariul net este $salNet";

?>

<form method="post" action="/">
    <label>Introduceti salariul dvs. <u>brut</u></label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="salarBrut" value=""/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Calculate!"/>
</form>
```

Should work.